# Estimate grid cell area from satelite data using a Stereographic polar projection

Tags: r, area, polar-coordinates, satellite

I am trying to work with satelite data from polar regions. They can be download as .nc (netcdf, see below).
They are in polar stereographic projection in a regular grid (https://nsidc.org/data/polar-stereo/ps_grids.html).
I would like to estimate each cell area to calculate the area of ice cover by multiplying the fraction of ice cover in each cell with the area of the cell.

I am able to extract cell area using "area" from {raster} only when the uniform grid is in geographical coordinates (lat-lon). However I could not find any R function to do this when the grid is uniform in stereographic coordinates.

I am very new to spatial data and projections and perhaps I am missing something important.
Below some relevant information and a piece of code with two trials.

### RELEVANT DATA AND INFORMATION SOURCES

Polar Watch
https://polarwatch.noaa.gov/erddap/

Sea Ice concentration data
url to downoald data

[https://polarwatch.noaa.gov/erddap/griddap/nsidcCDRiceSQnhmday.nc?seaice_conc_monthly_cdr[(2019-12-16T00:00:00Z):1:(2019-12-16T00:00:00Z)][(5837500.0):1:(-5337500.0)][(-3837500.0):1:(3737500.0)]](https://polarwatch.noaa.gov/erddap/griddap/nsidcCDRiceSQnhmday.nc?seaice_conc_monthly_cdr%5B(2019-12-16T00:00:00Z):1:(2019-12-16T00:00:00Z)%5D%5B(5837500.0):1:(-5337500.0)%5D%5B(-3837500.0):1:(3737500.0)%5D)

Can be download in R using

```
url1<- "https://polarwatch.noaa.gov/erddap/griddap/nsidcCDRiceSQnhmday.nc?seaice_conc_monthly_cdr[(2019-12-16T00:00:00Z):1:(2019-12-16T00:00:00Z)][(5837500.0):1:(-5337500.0)][(-3837500.0):1:(3737500.0)]"

download.file(url1, destfile='nsidcCDRiceSQnhmday_935c_47bd_a147.nc')
```

Data for the grid
Sea Ice Concentration Lat-Lon Grid, NOAA/NSIDC Climate Data Record V3,
Antarctic, 25km
Dataset ID: nsidcCDRice_sh_grid
url
[https://polarwatch.noaa.gov/erddap/griddap/nsidcCDRice_sh_grid.nc?latitude[(4337500.0):1:(-3937500.0)][(-3937500.0):1:(3937500.0)],longitude[(4337500.0):1:(-3937500.0)][(-3937500.0):1:(3937500.0)]](https://polarwatch.noaa.gov/erddap/griddap/nsidcCDRice_sh_grid.nc?latitude%5B(4337500.0):1:(-3937500.0)%5D%5B(-3937500.0):1:(3937500.0)%5D,longitude%5B(4337500.0):1:(-3937500.0)%5D%5B(-3937500.0):1:(3937500.0)%5D)

```
url2<- "https://polarwatch.noaa.gov/erddap/griddap/nsidcCDRice_sh_grid.nc?latitude[(4337500.0):1:(-3937500.0)][(-3937500.0):1:(3937500.0)],longitude[(4337500.0):1:(-3937500.0)][(-3937500.0):1:(3937500.0)]"

download.file(url2, destfile="nsidcCDRice_sh_grid_c513_9d75_76c1.nc")
```

https://nsidc.org/data/polar-stereo/ps_grids.html
Table 4. Southern Hemisphere Projection Based on WGS 1984
Latitude of True Origin     -70

#### SOME R TRIALS

```
require(raster)
require(ncdf4)

br<-brick("nsidcCDRiceSQnhmday_935c_47bd_a147.nc")
projection(br)<- CRS("+init=epsg:3976 +proj=stere +lat_0=-90 +lat_ts=-70 +lon_0=0 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs") #https://polarwatch.noaa.gov/tools-training/code-gallery/
br

res(br)

area(br)
```

which gives

```
Warning message:
In .local(x, ...) :
  This function is only useful for Raster* objects with a longitude/latitude coordinates
```

Using the grid provided in the data sources

```
IceFgrid<-nc_open("nsidcCDRice_sh_grid_c513_9d75_76c1.nc")

ygridLatLon <- ncvar_get(IceFgrid, varid="ygrid")
xgridLatLon <- ncvar_get(IceFgrid, varid="xgrid")
longitude <- ncvar_get(IceFgrid, varid="longitude")
latitude <- ncvar_get(IceFgrid, varid="latitude")
nc_close(IceFgrid)

dim(longitude) # Matrix with Longitude of each grid point.
length(xgridLatLon)
length(ygridLatLon)

## Try to convert to data frame and the to raster.

dims <- dim(longitude)
icemap.df <- data.frame(Longitude=array(longitude,dims[1]*dims[2]),
                        Latitude=array(latitude,dims[1]*dims[2]))
icemap.df$Seaice <- array(1,dims[1]*dims[2])# Here I use 1 for ice cover just

rast<-rasterFromXYZ(icemap.df, crs="+proj=stere +lat_0=-90 +lat_ts=-70 +lon_0=0 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6378273 +b=6356889.449 +units=m +no_defs")
```

But gives

```
Error in rasterFromXYZ(icemap.df, crs = "+proj=stere +lat_0=-90 +lat_ts=-70 +lon_0=0 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6378273 +b=6356889.449 +units=m +no_defs") : 
  x cell sizes are not regular
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance
Angel

Answer (score 0):

Here I use `terra` the replacement for `raster`

```
url1 <- "https://polarwatch.noaa.gov/erddap/griddap/nsidcCDRiceSQnhmday.nc?seaice_conc_monthly_cdr[(2019-12-16T00:00:00Z):1:(2019-12-16T00:00:00Z)][(5837500.0):1:(-5337500.0)][(-3837500.0):1:(3737500.0)]"

f <- 'nsidcCDRiceSQnhmday_935c_47bd_a147.nc'
download.file(url1, destfile='nsidcCDRiceSQnhmday_935c_47bd_a147.nc', mode="wb")
library(terra)
#terra version 1.3.4
r <- rast(f)
crs(r) <- "epsg:3976"

r
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 448, 304, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 25000, 25000  (x, y)
extent      : -3850000, 3750000, -5350000, 5850000  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=stere +lat_0=-90 +lat_ts=-70 +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs 
source      : nsidcCDRiceSQnhmday_935c_47bd_a147.nc 
varname     : seaice_conc_monthly_cdr (NOAA/NSIDC Climate Data Record of Passive Microwave Monthly Northern Hemisphere Sea Ice Concentration) 
name        : seaice_conc_monthly_cdr 
unit        :                       1 
time        : 2019-12-16
```

As you can see, the nominal cell resolution is 25000 x 25000

```
res(r)
[1] 25000 25000
```

Because it is constant, `raster` does not want to compute it for you. But `terra` will give you either the naïve area (based on the constant the nominal resolution):

```
na <- cellSize(r, transform=FALSE)
minmax(na)
#         area
#[1,] 6.25e+08
#[2,] 6.25e+08
```

Or the the *true* area. That is, accounting for distortion:

```
a <- cellSize(r, mask=F, unit="m", transform=TRUE)
a <- mask(a, r)
a 
#class       : SpatRaster 
#dimensions  : 448, 304, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 25000, 25000  (x, y)
#extent      : -3850000, 3750000, -5350000, 5850000  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : +proj=stere +lat_0=-90 +lat_ts=-70 +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs 
#source      : memory 
#name        :      area 
#min value   : 385538624
#max value   : 664449196 
#time        : 2019-12-16 

plot(a)
```

[image]

To get the sea-ice area in km<sup>2</sup>

```
x <- r * a / 1000000
global(x, "sum", na.rm=TRUE)
#                             sum
#_conc_monthly_cdr 11312232
```

The naïve estimate yields

```
n <- r * prod(res(r)) / 1000000
global(n, "sum", na.rm=TRUE)
#                             sum
#seaice_conc_monthly_cdr 11134025
```

That is about 1.5% lower

```
round(11134025 / 11312232, 3)
#[1] 0.984
```

This is not *that* different, because there is no ice at the edges, in the areas of severe distortion. And there is also some compensation in the central area (both smaller and larger areas) than 25*25 km<sup>2</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Despite it says resolution is uniform, there is a distortion and cells are not uniform along latitude. Thus I believe this approach is not usefull.

Comment: I have extended my answer

Comment: Hi Robert, This is awesome! Thanks for expanding your answer to explain the problem in detail. I will go through this definitely. I upvoted the question... but as long as I am new it is not recorded. regards