# R Terra package Error:[area] area(x, sum=FALSE) will be removed. Use "cellSize(x)"

Tags: r, spatial, netcdf, r-raster, terra

I am trying to replicate the answer to the following question but am getting errors on the R Terra area command:

[Estimate grid cell area from satelite data using a Stereographic polar projection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67422782/estimate-grid-cell-area-from-satelite-data-using-a-stereographic-polar-projectio/67423423#67423423)

The exact code I am running is the following:

```
url1 <- "https://polarwatch.noaa.gov/erddap/griddap/nsidcCDRiceSQnhmday.nc?seaice_conc_monthly_cdr[(2019-12-16T00:00:00Z):1:(2019-12-16T00:00:00Z)][(5837500.0):1:(-5337500.0)][(-3837500.0):1:(3737500.0)]"
f <- 'nsidcCDRiceSQnhmday_935c_47bd_a147.nc'
download.file(url1, destfile=f, mode="wb")
library(terra)
r <- rast(f)
crs(r) <- "epsg:3976"
res(r)
a <- area(r, correct=TRUE, mask=TRUE, sum=FALSE)
```

printing r yields

```
class       : SpatRaster
dimensions  : 448, 304, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 25000, 25000  (x, y)
extent      : -3850000, 3750000, -5350000, 5850000  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=stere +lat_0=-90 +lat_ts=-70 +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 
+units=m +no_defs 
source      : nsidcCDRiceSQnhmday_935c_47bd_a147.nc 
varname     : seaice_conc_monthly_cdr (NOAA/NSIDC Climate Data Record of Passive 
Microwave Monthly Northern Hemisphere Sea Ice Concentration) 
name        : seaice_conc_monthly_cdr 
unit        :                       1 
time        : 2019-12-16
```

I receive the following error on the line with the area() command:

```
Error: [area] area(x, sum=FALSE) will be removed. Use "cellSize(x)"
```

I have tried this on my default R instance and have also setup a clean one from scratch. I get the same error on both installs. Both systems are macOS. If I try to change the area command to a cellSize command, R quits altogether and restarts.

Here is the sessionInfo() for each setup:

System 2: Clean Install MacOS Big Sur

```
R version 4.1.0 (2021-05-18)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Big Sur 11.2.3

Matrix products: default
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] raster_3.4-12 sp_1.4-5      Rcpp_1.0.7    ncdf4_1.17    terra_1.3-13 

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] lattice_0.20-44   codetools_0.2-18  digest_0.6.27     grid_4.1.0       
 [5] evaluate_0.14     rlang_0.4.11      rmarkdown_2.9     tools_4.1.0      
 [9] xfun_0.24         yaml_2.2.1        compiler_4.1.0    htmltools_0.5.1.1
[13] knitr_1.33
```

System 1: macOS Catalina

```
R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Catalina 10.15.7

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base    

other attached packages:
[1] terra_1.2-10   raster_3.4-5   sp_1.4-4       downloader_0.4 XML_3.99-0.5  
[6] RCurl_1.98-1.2

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.5        rerddap_0.7.4     pillar_1.4.7      compiler_4.0.2  
 [5] bitops_1.0-6      tools_4.0.2       ncdf4_1.17        digest_0.6.27    
 [9] lattice_0.20-41   jsonlite_1.7.1    evaluate_0.14     lifecycle_0.2.0  
[13] tibble_3.0.4      gtable_0.3.0      pkgconfig_2.0.3   rlang_0.4.8      
[17] rstudioapi_0.13   crul_1.1.0        curl_4.3          yaml_2.2.1      
[21] xfun_0.19         dplyr_1.0.2       httr_1.4.2        knitr_1.30      
[25] xml2_1.3.2        generics_0.1.0    vctrs_0.3.5       rappdirs_0.3.3  
[29] grid_4.0.2        tidyselect_1.1.0  glue_1.4.2        httpcode_0.3.0  
[33] data.table_1.13.2 R6_2.5.0          rmarkdown_2.5     purrr_0.3.4      
[37] ggplot2_3.3.2     hoardr_0.5.2      magrittr_1.5      codetools_0.2-16
[41] scales_1.1.1      ellipsis_0.3.1    htmltools_0.5.0   colorspace_2.0-0
[45] tinytex_0.27      munsell_0.5.0     crayon_1.3.4
```

Comment: I just ran this same code and got the same error (in RStudio). I also ran the `terra::area` [sample code](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/terra/versions/1.1-4/topics/area), and got the same error. So, I'm wondering if it is a bug. I'd comment (and link to this post) on Hijmans post. You might also want to submit a [issue on github](https://github.com/rspatial/terra/issues) as well for `terra::area`.

Comment: i get a segfault in terminal ubuntu 20.04, R-4.1.0. Guess I didn't build it in debug as my core dump is not very informative ????. Gotta love `Julia Evans`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the messages says, the `area` method was replaced by `cellSize` (to avoid a name clash with `spatstat`).

I have updated the answer to the [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67423423/635245) to reflect the current version of terra.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am able to run the example now. I switched to using the development version of terra that you referenced and used the cellSize command as updated in the original example and it worked as expected.